# How to brand the top link bar?

Tags: css, branding, top-link-bar

I created a SharePoint Foundation site and want to brand the top link bar.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, much if not all of this can be accomplished through CSS.

Here are some postings from Erik Swenson's [SharePoint Branding and Design blog](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/) on how to get started:

[SharePoint 2010 Base CSS Classes](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-base-css-classes.html)

[Navigation Drop Down Styles](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-navigation-drop-down.html)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a "How To" for EUSP - hope it helps: [Adding-a-touch-of-Glamour-Part-Two-The-Menu](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Adding-a-touch-of-Glamour-Part-Two-The-Menu.aspx) - it shows the classes you change to style the Top navigation bar.

Comment: "Louise van der Bijl" please check your "HOW TO" page on the branding, since there's a important question you never replied to and its useless until resolved thank you all , great resources

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get a lot of brandinding questions in proccess of Sharepoint customization. If so, it will be very helpfull to read this book: [Professional SharePoint 2010 Branding and User Interface Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470584645)